# AS3 How to make a variable hold only objects that implements a given interface

Tags: actionscript-3, interface, typechecking

I have two classes, lines and points. Both class implements 'highlightable'. I want to make a variable that can hold different type of objects that implements the 'highlightable' interface.

```
var currentObject:lines; //Won't work. It can only hold 'lines' object.
var currentObject:points; //won't work because it can only hold 'points' object.
var currentObject:Object; //Won't work because it can hold any objects. I want it to hold only those objects that implements the 'highlightable' interface.
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is make your variable the type of your interface.

```
var currentObject:highlightable = new classA();
```

or

```
var currentObject:highlightable = new classB();
```

Where both classA and classB implement the highlightable interface.

Answer (score 4):

Just implement the interface in your class so you force the pattern.

```
public interface IHighlightable

public class Lines implements IHighlightable
public class Points implements IHighlightable


// for the usage you type cast as the interface
var currentObject:IHighlightable = new Lines()
var currentObject:IHighlightable = new Points()
```

**Be sure to follow naming conventions